Compactification of the Jacobian of singular curves via parabolic modules
I would like to better understand a certain compactification of the Jacobian variety of a singular algebraic plane curve as described in Cook's Ph.D. 1993 thesis Local and Global Aspects
of the Module Theory of Singular Curves. So far, I have only been able to find references discussing this compactification for the case of simple/ADE singularities (e.g. [1] [2]).
Question: Is there some kind of obstruction and/or limitation of our current tools that prevents this compactification from working for arbitrary singularities? What parts of the aforementioned construction in Cook's thesis crucially rely on the assumption that every singularity of the curve is simple?
[1] Emilio Franco, Robert Hanson, Johannes Horn, André Oliveira, Fourier-Mukai transforms and normalization of nodal curves, https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.11860
[2] Peter B. Gothen, André Oliveira, The singular fibre of the Hitchin map, Int. Math. Res. Notices 2013 no. 5 (2013), 1079-1121. https://doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rns020. https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5541

Can you be more precise about what results you have in mind. A number of results extend to the case where the curve has at worst planar singularities. Without some assumption like this, the moduli space can be very badly behaved (many irreducible components, not equi-dimensional, nonreduced,....)
